# How to create getbaseurl in php framework zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

How can i create baseurl method in zend so that it can be accessible to all the project files like model,form,view etc. can i create any in php

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

I think you should study [Naming Conventions in Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html):

> Zend Framework standardizes on a class
>   naming convention whereby the names of
>   the classes directly map to the
>   directories in which they are stored.
>   The root level directory of Zend
>   Framework's standard library is the
>   "Zend/" directory, whereas the root
>   level directory of Zend Framework's
>   extras library is the "ZendX/"
>   directory. All Zend Framework classes
>   are stored hierarchically under these
>   root directories..

And you can get base url in zend something like this:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
```